# ctypes and accessing com interface methods

Tags: python, pointers, interface, com, ctypes

I am trying to load audio from Windows Media Foundation using python ctypes and coms, but having trouble getting it to work.

The issue is I need an `IMFAttributes` interface object to use it's methods after creation, in this example `SetUINT32`. So to get the object of a pointer I am using `attrib_config.contents`, which does return an `IMAttributes` object. However, trying to access any methods to it causes a read access error.

Here is the relevant code, without spamming the entire file.

```
class IMFAttributes(com.IUnknown):
    _methods_ = [
         .....
         ('SetUINT32',
         com.STDMETHOD(POINTER(GUID), c_uint32))
    ]

MFCreateAttributes = mfplat.MFCreateAttributes
MFCreateAttributes.restype = HRESULT
MFCreateAttributes.argtypes = [POINTER(POINTER(IMFAttributes)), c_uint32]
```

Which should match what Microsoft recommends:

```
HRESULT MFCreateAttributes(
  IMFAttributes **ppMFAttributes,
  UINT32        cInitialSize
)
```

Basically one double pointer, and int32.

So I have initialized everything and create it as such:

```
MF_LOW_LATENCY = com.GUID(0x9c27891a, 0xed7a, 0x40e1, 0x88, 0xe8, 0xb2, 0x27, 0x27, 0xa0, 0x24, 0xee)

MFStartup(MF_VERSION, 0)

attrib_config = POINTER(IMFAttributes)()
result = MFCreateAttributes(byref(attrib_config), 1)

attrib_config.contents.SetUINT32(byref(MF_LOW_LATENCY), 1)
```

result returns as `S_OK` (0), but after I attempt to use `SetUINT32`, I instantly get `OSError: exception: access violation reading 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`

I am new to ctypes, so any help would really be appreciated.